# Detecting reason for the screen turning ON

Tags: android, android-service

What I have so far is a `Service` with a registered `BroadcastReceiver` for the following actions: `ACTION_SCREEN_ON/ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`.

So far so good. If the screen goes ON or OFF I get the notification. But this happens for various reasons: user pushes a button (POWER, HOME, etc), battery gets fully charged, incoming call, etc.

What I need is to detect what was the reason for turning the screen ON. And more precisely to detect if it was because of the user pushing power or home button. I've read some opinions that there is no reliable way to do this, but would like to ask again before giving up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try using [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getState%28%29); You can than get following states for the screen: `STATE_OFF`, `STATE_ON`, `STATE_DOZE`, `STATE_DOZE_SUSPEND`, or `STATE_UNKNOWN`. It is not exactly what you needed, but I hope it could help you a little bit.